# Accessing Object value

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a web app based on Flask, SQLAlchemy and Jinja2, but I cannot get an object value when making a join with SQLAlchemy. For example, I have 2 objects like this in my `models.py`:

```
def user:
    id = dbcolumn (integer )
    username =dbcolumn (varchar(whatever))
    local_id = dbcolumn(integer)

def local:
    id = dbcolumn (integer )
    local_name =dbcolumn (varchar(whatever))
```

in my `routes.py` file, if I do:

```
    qry = User.query.filter(id=1)
    usertoshow = qry.first()
    print(usertoshow)
    ...
    return render_template('editaruser.html', form=form, user=userupd)
```

the result in print will return something like `<User James>`. If I want to show the results in HTML with Jinja, I just do `{{ user.username }}` and the data is shown correctly, although I need to do several joins to gather all data I need. For instance, when I do a join like:

```
    qry = db.session.query(User, Local).join(Local, (Local.id==User.user_local_id))
    print(qry)
    userupd = qry.first()
    print(userupd)
```

The query returned in print (qry) is

```
    SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.user_nome AS user_user_nome, user.email AS user_email, user.password_hash AS user_password_hash, user.user_local_id AS user_user_local_id, user.user_terapeuta_id AS user_user_terapeuta_id, user.user_date_crea AS user_user_date_crea, user.user_created_by AS user_user_created_by, user.user_last_login AS user_user_last_login, user.user_activo AS user_user_activo, local.id AS local_id, local.local_nome AS local_local_nome
    FROM user INNER JOIN local ON local.id = user.user_local_id
```

and the result in the 2nd print is

```
(<User Jamesdean>, <Local Somewhere in the world>)
```

I thought that I was creating some kind of object that could be called in Jinja2 like:

```
    <td>Username:</td><td>{{ user.username }} {{ user.local_nome }}</td>
```

But this returns empty and no error is returned, only a blank space where once it was a username before I did the join.

How may I get the data retrieved from the query present here: `(<User Jamesdean>, <Local Somewhere in the world>)`?

Comment: Just found It. You need to reference the type of data you need, in my case it should be {{ user.User.username }} {{ user.Local.local_name }}. Thanks and sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Just found It. You need to reference the type of data you need, in my case it should be {{ user.User.username }} {{ user.Local.local_name }}.